# PHP different locations for images and thumbs

Tags: php

I have found some solution that work mostly but none that do the trick 100% what I am looking for is code that will look in all my albums in one directory and pull the images and also pull my thumbs that are in another folder and echo out the a string like this.

```
echo '<a href="',$img,'" rel="shadowbox"><img src="',$img,'" /></a>';
```

The problem is that my href image is in my images folder and my src (thumbnails) are in another directory.  I am using shadowbox and want the script to echo out a stirng that will allow both the directories to be scanned at the same time.

Below is what I am using that does scan the directorys but will not return the coresponding enter code herethumbnails that reside in another directory

```
//path to directory to scan. i have included a wildcard for a subdirectory
$directory = "gallery_uploads/*/";

//get all image files with a .jpg extension.
$images = glob("" . $directory . "*.jpg");

$imgs = '';
// create array
foreach($images as $image){ $imgs[] = "$image"; }


//display images
foreach ($imgs as $img) {
     "<a href='$img' rel='shadowbox'><img src='$img' /> ";


     echo'<a href="',$img,'" rel="shadowbox"><img src="',$img,'" /></a>';
```

Comment: Use a database for referencing images, one column for the thumbs and the other for the full image.

Comment: Do the filenames of the thumbnails have a relation with the names of the full images?
And yes, @Daryl Gill has a very valid point. Use a database or another type of storage like XML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me. You would have to make sure your images have the same name in each directory though.

It is very simple to have your uploader save the original, then save a resized image of the same name in the thumbnail directory.

```
$gallery_up_dir = "gallery_uploads";
$gallery_thumb_dir = "gallery_thumbs";
$directory = "$gallery_up_dir/*/";

// or get all image files with a .jpg, .JPG, .png, .PNG extension.
$extensions_array = array('jpg', 'JPG', 'png', 'PNG');


$imageArray = array();
foreach($extensionsArray as $ext){
    $images = glob("" . $directory . "*.$ext");

    // fill up the array
    foreach($images as $image){ 
        $imageArray[] = "$image"; 
    }
}

//display images
foreach ($imageArray as $img) {

     echo '<a href="',$img,'" rel="shadowbox"><img src="', 
           str_replace($gallery_up_dir,$gallery_thumb_dir,$img) ,'" /></a>';

}
```

Comment: That worked awesome. Now the only other thing i need to know is how to have it scan for png files in the same directories as as the jpg.

Comment: Also, when I upload my files, it converts my png to thumbnails and regular, but I loose the transparancy?

Comment: The transparency issue is another question. Post it to the site with your snippet of code that does the transformation. If you have this issue, for sure someone else will have it too, or maybe already had it.