# PHP different locations for images and thumbs script

Tags: php, image

Hi i am trying to use the php answer to different locations for images and thumbs in below page
[PHP different locations for images and thumbs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15673245/php-different-locations-for-images-and-thumbs)

i get a
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/content/33/5055733/html/galeria.php on line 88

line 87 - 89 is below

```
$imageArray = array();
foreach($extensionsArray as $ext){
$images = glob("" . $directory . "*.$ext");
```

Could anyone help please?
Thanks Melanie
below is the full code

```
<?php  
$gallery_up_dir = "gallery_uploads";
$gallery_thumb_dir = "gallery_thumbs";
$directory = "$gallery_up_dir/*/";

// or get all image files with a .jpg, .JPG, .png, .PNG extension.
$extensions_array = array('jpg', 'JPG', 'png', 'PNG');


$imageArray = array();
foreach($extensionsArray as $ext){
    $images = glob("" . $directory . "*.$ext");

    // fill up the array
    foreach($images as $image){ 
        $imageArray[] = "$image"; 
     }
}

//display images
foreach ($imageArray as $img) {

     echo '<a href="',$img,'" rel="shadowbox" class="thumbnail"><img src="', 
           str_replace($gallery_up_dir,$gallery_thumb_dir,$img) ,'" /></a>';

}?>
```

Comment: `$extensions_array` <-> `foreach($extensionsArray` … spot the difference.

Answer (score 3):

It is a typo. Change the `$extensions_array` to:

```
$extensionsArray = array('jpg', 'JPG', 'png', 'PNG');
```

as you're using the camel cased version in the foreach loop:

```
foreach($extensionsArray as $ext){ ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$extensions_array = array('jpg', 'JPG', 'png', 'PNG');

foreach($extensionsArray as $ext){
```

The variable are different, use $extensions_array or $extensionsArray in both places, and it should work